# How to merge two Android-Studio project's

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

i know this question has been asked several times. but i had to find out that it was a long time ago and there were no solutions.

## so my question:

i have a big project "A", for this project i have made and tested a subproject "a" in a separate app. Now I want to bring these projects together or rather inform, project "a" in "A".

what's the best approach?

Comment: import project a as module

Comment: do i still have to take care that certain resuourcen don't occur twice?

Comment: yep you should merge them

Answer (score 2):

You can import your second project as a Gradle Project to your first Android Studio Project.

You can import project via:

**1.a.** From Project view, click right click your project root and follow ***New/Module***. 
[image: New Module From Project View]

**1.b.** And then, choose "***Import Gradle Project***". 
[image: New Module]

**1.c.** Select your second project's ***module root***.

[image: Import Gradle Project]

---

**2.** You can follow ***File/New/New Module*** and same as *1.b.*
[image: New Module From File/New/Module]

---

**3.** You can follow ***File/New/Import Module*** and same as *1.c.*
[image: Import Module from File Menu]

---

When you imported existing Gradle Project, you can see it on the configurations drop-down menu. You can run, debug or even compile for release them separately.

Comment: this way i get two maifest files... do i get no problems this way?

Comment: I get some Errors:
Unable to resolve dependency for ':materialdesign@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :migraenetagebuch.

Comment: Error : Unable to resolve dependency for ':appa@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :appb.