# How do I download a GitHub repository to an Andriod Studio project that I am currently working on?

Tags: android, github

I am working on an Android Studio project and I would like to add a getup repository to the current project. I am using a Mac.

I have downloaded the Github repository and unzipped the folder and was able to create a NEW project using the GitHub repository in Android Studio, but I do not know how to either

A) merge the two projects in Android Studio so my initial project can use the new GitHub Repository Project.

or

B) if I did this process incorrectly and I need to add the GitHub repository directly to my initial Project. I just don't know how and I have looked everywhere for the answer. Any assistance would be fantastic.

[I found this answer about merging projects, but I do not know where to find my projects "module root"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915050/how-to-merge-two-android-studio-projects)

Comment: Are you planning on editing the contents of that repository?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to these 2 links, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093723/how-to-add-an-android-studio-project-to-github) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644946/how-do-you-synchronise-projects-to-github-with-android-studio) for elaborations.

First of all, open the project you want to push in Android Studio.

Click VCS -> Enable version Control Integration -> Git

There doesn't seem to be a way to add a remote through the GUI. So open Git Bash in the root of the project and do git remote add

Now when you do VCS -> Commit changes -> Commit & Push you should see your remote and everything should work through the GUI.

If you are getting the error: fatal: remote  already exists that means you already added it. To see your remotes do git remote -v and git remote rm  to remove.

You may also refer to [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-git-integration.html) and [here](http://gitref.org/remotes/) for more understanding.