# How to combine one android studio project into anotherAndroid studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

*I have two separate android app projects that were made in android studio I am trying to combine project 1 into project 2 to make it all one app how would I go about doing this? I know how to do it in eclipse but not in android studio*

Exemple
Intent intente = new intente (Mainactivite projet on, this.Mainactivite projet2.class)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two Android-Studio project's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915050/how-to-merge-two-android-studio-projects)

Comment: Thank you, I did these steps, but it did not work in Android Studio, it is already there, but how to move from the first project to the second